# PHP SimpleXML Values returned have weird characters in place of hyphens and apostrophes

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have looked around and can't seem to find a solution so here it is.

I have the following code:

```
$file = "adhddrugs.xml";
$xmlstr = simplexml_load_file($file);
echo $xmlstr->report_description;
```

This is the simple version, but even trying this any hyphens r apostrophes are turned into: ^a (euro sign) trademark sign.

Things I have tried are:

```
echo = (string)$xmlstr->report_description; /* did not work */
echo = addslashes($xmlstr->report_description); /* yes I know this doesnt work with hyphens, was mainly trying to see if I could escape the apostrophes */
echo = addslashes((string)$xmlstr->report_description); /* did not work */
```

also htmlspecial(again i know does not work with hyphens), htmlentities, and a few other tricks.

Now the situation is I am getting the XML files from a feed so I cannot change them, but they are pretty standard. The text with the hyphens etc are encapsulated in a cdata tag and encoding is UTF-8. If I check the source I am shown the hyphens and apostrophes in the source.

Now just to see if the encoding was off or mislabeled or something else weird, I tried to view the raw XML file and sure enough it is displayed correctly.

I am sure that in my rush to find the answer I have overlooked something simple and the fact that this is really the first time I have ever used SimpleXML I am missing a very simple solution. Just don't dock me for it I really did try and find the answer on my own.

Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks guys these both look good, I didn't see the responses until now and I am heading home, I will check those asap thanks again. I will let you know.

Comment: If you are looking for the solution, while Matt's answer is correct, please read Jasso and Takeshin's response because the three of them helped with the solution. 1. Explaining the why. 2. explaining how to fix it. 3. helping with settings in simpleXML that helped solve it also. using one of them may fix it but looking at all the answers will make sure it fixes the issue and help you understand the issue so that you don't make this mistake again. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know the document's character set?

You could do `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` before any content is printed, if you havent already.

Comment: Perfect worked great! Thanks, I don't know why I didn't try this before now. I guess I thought the issue was larger than a simple header label issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

> This is the simple version, but even
>   trying this any hyphens apostrophes
>   are turned into: ^a (euro sign)
>   trademark sign.

This is caused by incorrect charset guessing (and possibly recoding).

If a text contains a "curly apostrophe" = "Right single quotation mark" = U+2019 character, saving it in UTF-8 encoding results in bytes `0xE2 0x80 0x99`. If the same file is then read again *assuming* its charset is windows-1252, the byte stream of the apostrophe character (`0xE2 0x80 0x99`) is interpreted as characters `â€™` (=small "a" with circumflex, euro sign, trademark sign). Again if this incorrectly interpreted text is saved as UTF-8 the original character results in byte stream `0xC3 0xA2 0xE2 0x82 0xAC 0xE2 0x84 0xA2`

Summary: Your original data is UTF-8 and some part of your code that reads the data assumes it is windows-1252 (or ISO-8859-1, which is usually actually treated as windows-1252). A probable reason for this charset assumption is that default charset for HTTP is ISO-8859-1. 'When no explicit charset parameter is provided by the sender, media subtypes of the "text" type are defined to have a default charset value of "ISO-8859-1" when received via HTTP.' Source: [RFC 2616, Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)

PS. this is a very common problem. Just do a Google or Bing search with query `doesnâ€™t -doesn't` and you'll see many pages with this same encoding error.

Comment: This was a brilliant response, thanks. Understanding the issue helped not only solving the problem but also solving it in the future. The "Teach a man to fish ..." thing. I wish more people would explain the why more instead of just giving the answer. That being said after reading your response Matt's answer is 100% correct, and he was the first to post it, I just feel stupid for not trying it before. Thanks so much for your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have set up SimpleXML to use UTF-8 too.

Be sure that all the entities are encoded using hex notation, not HTML entities.

Also maybe:

```
$string = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");
```

will help.

Comment: Thanks, I did make sure that SimpleXML was using UTF-8 and while your code example in theory should be the same as using a header statement it did not seem to work. Part of your answer along with Matt and Jasso helped solve the problem. So thanks.

Comment: How to set up SimpleXML to use UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

This is a symptom of declaring an incorrect character set in the `<head>` section of your page (or not declaring and using default character set without accents and special characters).

This does the trick for latin languages.

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

For TOTAL NEWBIES, html pages for browsers have a basic layout, with a HEAD or HEADER which serves to tell the browser some basic stuff about the page, as well as preload some scripts that the page will use to achieve its functionality(ies).

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  Hello world
 </body>
</html>
```

if the `<head>` section is omitted, html will use defaults (take some things for granted - like using the northamerican character set, which does NOT include many accented letters, whch show up as "weird characters".