# SimpleXML and french characters

Tags: php, xml, encoding, simplexml, special-characters

I work for a International company and thus we have loads of languages to cater for.
I'm having a problem with some special characters.

I created a standalone test php page to eliminate any other issues that could be introduced by my system.

From various pages i read through i found that SimpleXML processed XML as UTF-8.
Eg : [PHP SimpleXML Values returned have weird characters in place of hyphens and apostrophes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833805/php-simplexml-values-returned-have-weird-charectors-in-place-of-hyphens-and-apos)

SO i did just that at top of the page:

```
header("Content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

THen i did this to check :

```
print mb_internal_encoding();
```

Not sure if this is the right function but it gave me ISO-8859-1 in FF and Chome.

XML looks like this:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<Tracking>
<File>
<FileNumber>çúé$`~  €   Š   š   Ž   ž   Œ   œ   Ÿ</FileNumber>
<OrigBranch>124</OrigBranch>
<Login></Login>
</File>
</Tracking>';
```

This prints out all funny, but for the page i need, i'm not too concrened how it prints out in browser as the actual page will actually run from a cron to import the XML into a MYSQL DB, so dislay not too important. It displays on FF like this though

```
print $xml;
���$`~ � � � � � � � � � 124
```

Then i create the SimpleXML object :

```
$parser = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
print_r($parser);
```

This prints out :

```
[File] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [FileNumber] => çúé$`~                           
        [OrigBranch] => 124
        [Login] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

    )
```

I'm not too worried about the funny characters in the print $xml;, but more need to fix the characters in the SimpleXMLElement Object that is being inserted into the DB.
Why is the SimpleXMLElement Object losing the character after the '~'. I tried to change the charset to ISO-8859-15 in header function call, but this only lead to the print $xml; looking slightly better , but still missing characters after '~', but SimpleXMLElement give fatal error :

```
'String could not be parsed as XML
```

I tried before parsing XML :

```
$xml = mb_convert_encoding($xml, "ISO-8859-15");
$xml = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-15//TRANSLIT', $xml)
```

But these did not help either.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a specific file in latin1(`ISO-8859-1`) named `latin1.xml` with this content (you can add `encoding="UTF-8"` in the xml tag, it's the same):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Tracking>
<File>
<FileNumber>çùé$ °à §çòò àù§</FileNumber>
<OrigBranch>124</OrigBranch>
<Login></Login>
</File>
</Tracking>
```

Then I loaded the content in the php file and made the conversion from `ISO-8859-1` to `UTF-8`, after that the parsing with `SimpleXMLElement`.
I echoed the content of the xml before

```
<?php
$xml = file_get_contents('latin1.xml');
echo '<pre>'.$xml.'</pre>'."<br>";
$xml2 = iconv("ISO-8859-1","UTF-8",$xml);
echo '<pre>'.$xml2.'</pre>'."<br>";
$parser = new SimpleXMLElement($xml2);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($parser).'</pre>'."<br>";
```

Now loading the script, if your browser is set with UTF-8 econding, the first echo will be rightly not well shown but it will be ok the second and the `print_r($parser)`. Otherwise if the browser is set with ISO-8859-1 then you will see the first echo good but not the second and the print_r.

You can adjust to fit your needs.

**UPDATE**

ISO/IEC 8859-1 is missing some characters for French and Finnish text, as well as the euro sign.
If I understand well your comments you can have the source file (xml) in `ISO-8859-15`, in this way you can use correctly the euro sign.
I made a new file, named `iso8859-15.xml`, and put you new test characters there (with euro sign too). In the php file I changed the first instruction:

```
//$xml = file_get_contents('latin1.xml');
$xml = file_get_contents('iso8859-15.xml');
```

and, later, the conversion in:

```
$xml2 = iconv("ISO-8859-15","UTF-8",$xml);
```

Now loading the script, if your browser is set with UTF-8 econding, the first echo will be rightly not well shown but it will be ok the second and the `print_r($parser)`, the output of SimpleXml.

So, now that you have your parsed xml rightly (in `UTF-8`) you can convert it before write on DB (that is in `ISO-8859-15` encoding, if I correctly understood).
To be more clear you can add this line, at the end, to the php script above:

```
echo '<pre> File number in ISO-8859-15 for db: '.iconv("UTF-8","ISO-8859-15",$parser->File->FileNumber).'</pre>'."<br>";
```

As you can see I converted the `UTF-8` data from the simpleXml in `ISO-8859-15`, as you should do when you'll write on DB.
That worked for me.

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks Stramaz.

I tried different combinations. I did away with the chars "Š   š   Ž   ž   Œ   œ   Ÿ" as i don't see it being used that often, but the "€" is vital. New test special char string :

    çúé$`~ € °à §çòò àù§ 

page charset=UTF-8 + XML encoding="UTF-8" -> print XML funny chars, SImpleXML breaks

page charset=ISO-8859-1 + XML encoding="UTF-8" -> print XML good,   SImpleXML breaks. which is surprising as i thought "€" only available from ISO-8859-15

page charset=ISO-8859-1 + XML encoding="ISO-8859-1" -> xml good, SImpleXML funny chars

Comment: ...continued

page charset=ISO-8859-15 + XML encoding="ISO-8859-15" -> xml good, SImpleXML funny chars

the pages viewing the info saved by this SImpleXML object into the DB is all rendered with charset=ISO-8859-15. So the important part for me is to get the char correct in SImpleXML object and therefore correct going into the DB.

Comment: I made and update on my Answer, it should help you. Let me know

Comment: thanks Stramaz. This put me on the right path. 
The iconv("UTF-8","ISO-8859-15",$parser->File->FileNumber) did the trick to overcome SimpleXML UTF8 output. I had to loop thru all the values though as doing iconv("UTF-8","ISO-8859-15",$parser) failed. I also had to use ISO-8859-1 instead as ISO-8859-15 the € sign was missing. Not sure why since I thought € sign was only available in ISO-8859-15.

Answer (score 0):

If you build XML, try to base64 decode all strings and then on the client side where you read the XML encode them back

Answer (score -1):

Try `$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>...`